# Optional ValidationAttributes in ASP.NET Mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I’m using ASP.NET Mvc 4 and ran into a conceptional problem while building a form which should allow the user to insert a complex datastructure into the Db. 
Consider the following datamodel:

[image]

Lets assume we want to create a customer (Businessrule: Each customer can have billing- and deliveryaddress but must have a default address as fallback).

The View probably would look like this:

[image]

The address-types were rendered as strongly-typed partialviews. I populated the Model of the partial Address-View with annotations like [Required] for Street,ZIP and Country to assure that an address will be inserted according to the underlying constraints. I render „Create-Customer“- like this… 
Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateCustomer()
{
  var model = new CustomerModel();
  var addresses = new AddressModel[]{
    new AddressModel { AddressTypeId = 1 },//Default, required
    new AddressModel { AddressTypeId = 2 },//Billing, optional!
    new AddressModel { AddressTypeId = 3 }//Delivery, optional!
  };
  model.Addresses = addresses.ToList();
  return View(model);
}
```

CreateCustomer (View):

```
    ….Name, Number,…
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.Addresses.Count; i++)
  {
    ViewBag.CurrentAddressKindName = Model.Addresses[i].AddressKindName;    
    <fieldset>
      <legend>@ViewBag.CurrentAddressKindName</legend>
      @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Address/_FormFields.cshtml", Model.Addresses[i]);}
    </fieldset>
  }
…
```

Now for the problem:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateCustomer(CustomerModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return BadRequest();
  }
  return Ok();
}
```

When posting the form back to the server, ModelState.IsValid – obviously – returns false when for instance only default- and billing-addresses are populated because of the ([Required],…) annotations in the address-model. What I want to achieve is to require (validate) the default address but ignore the validation of optional addressTypes (But only, if they are empty!)
It looks like I got stuck on a conceptional problem here. Any gotchas? :D

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need 2 separate address view models, one with the `[Required]` attributes and one without, or one with and additional property (say) `bool IsRequired` and use conditional validation attributes such as a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Thanks for your reply. It's definitely a possible way to go. I already found a Post on stackoverflow pointing out Annotations like RequiredIf. But since I have to install additional libraries to use them and I want to keep it as simple as possible (using this Method I have to duplicate the logic for every annotation which looks like a codesmell...DRY), I was wondering if there isn't any built in way to suppress/disable some annotations before actually calling ModelState.IsValid...

Comment: You can use fluent validation for this refer this link : https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreatingAValidator

Comment: In all cases, to be able to ignore some validations, you need to write some code, either on the client side or the server side, possible solutions, 1 - as Stephan mentioned to use Annotation RequiredIf, 2- or to use IValidatableObject on the server side, 3-  or to use JQuery on the client side to prevent sending the optional empty address

Comment: A custom attribute similar to `RequiredIf` could solve both cases without different viewmodel types.  Always require other fields if any field is present, and make the entry required if the address type == 1

Comment: @Alan, No there is no _built in way to suppress/disable some annotations_. There are various hacks you can use such as removing the `data-val-*` attributes on the client and clearing ModelState` errors in the controller, but its fragile and will result in more code anyway.

Comment: I finally decided to go for the [RequiredIf]-attribute. Thanks to all :)